# call android activity method via QAndroidJniObject

Tags: android, qt

Hello everybody  I want to call this method "printTextTemplate ()" from an android activity class to Qt via QAndroidJniObject but I can't get it to work. here is my java class below

```
package org.qtproject.example.activityhandler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import android.bld.print.configuration.PrintConfig;
import com.example.lc_print_sdk.PrintUtil;
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;

import org.qtproject.example.activityhandler.utils.BitmapUtils;
import org.qtproject.example.activityhandler.R;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public  class CustomActivity extends Activity {

    PrintUtil printUtil;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        printUtil=PrintUtil.getInstance (this);
        //printUtil.setPrintEventListener (this);
        printUtil.printEnableMark (false);



        Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String sessionId = "Hello Alioune";
                Intent inputIntent = getIntent();
                sessionId = inputIntent.getStringExtra("message");

                //printTextTemplate();
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                resultIntent.putExtra("message", sessionId);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void printTextTemplate() {

       BitmapDrawable drawable=(BitmapDrawable) getResources ().getDrawable (R.drawable.a);
       Bitmap bitmap=BitmapUtils.compressPic(drawable.getBitmap(), 350, 160);
       printUtil.printBitmap(bitmap);

       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_CENTER, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_MIDDLE, false, false, "------------------------------------------------------\n");

       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_CENTER, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_LARGE, true, true, "CONTROL ROUTIER\n");

       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_CENTER, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_MIDDLE, false, false, "------------------------------------------------------\n");

       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_LEFT, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_MIDDLE, false, false, "Référence:\n\n");
       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_LEFT, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_MIDDLE, false, false, "Date：\n\n");
       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_LEFT, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_MIDDLE, false, false, "Validité:\n\n");
       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_LEFT, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_MIDDLE, false, false, "Agent：\n");
       printUtil.printLine (1);


       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_CENTER, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_MIDDLE, false, false, "------------------------------------------------------\n");

       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_CENTER, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_LARGE, true, true, "CAMIONS\n");

       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_CENTER, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_MIDDLE, false, false, "------------------------------------------------------\n");

       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_LEFT, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_MIDDLE, false, false, "Immatriculation:\n\n");
       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_LEFT, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_MIDDLE, false, false, "Chauffeur：\n\n");
       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_LEFT, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_MIDDLE, false, false, "Produit Chargé:\n");

       printUtil.printLine (1);


       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_CENTER, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_MIDDLE, false, false, "------------------------------------------------------\n");

       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_CENTER, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_LARGE, true, true, "CONFIRMATION\n");

       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_CENTER, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_MIDDLE, false, false, "------------------------------------------------------\n");

       BitmapDrawable drawable1=(BitmapDrawable) getResources ().getDrawable (R.drawable.b);
       Bitmap bitmap1=BitmapUtils.compressPic(drawable1.getBitmap(), 300, 300);
       printUtil.printBitmap(bitmap1);

       printUtil.printLine (1);

       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_CENTER, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_MIDDLE, false, false, "------------------------------------------------------\n");

       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_CENTER, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_LARGE, true, true, "POSTE DE DOUANE BITOU\n");

       printUtil.printText (PrintConfig.Align.ALIGN_CENTER, PrintConfig.FontSize.TOP_FONT_SIZE_MIDDLE, false, false, "------------------------------------------------------\n");

       printUtil.printLine (8);
       printUtil.start ();
   }

}
```

Here is the method of calling in Qt

void ActivityHandler::printTextTemplate(){

```
QAndroidJniObject javaClass =
QAndroidJniObject("org/qtproject/example/activityhandler/CustomActivity",
"(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/app/Activity;)V",
QtAndroid::androidContext().object<jobject>(),
QtAndroid::androidActivity().object<jobject>());
```

javaClass.callMethod("printTextTemplate");
}

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be calling the constructor for `QAndroidJniObject`.

Instead you should try this:

```cpp
void ActivityHandler::printTextTemplate(){
  QAndroidJniObject activity = QtAndroid::androidActivity();
  if (activity.isValid()) {
    activity.callObjectMethod("printTextTemplate");
  }
}
```